# Modify txt file in python or linux on certain condition(e.g. find same values and max/min time)

Tags: python, linux, txt

I have a txt file I wish to modify. The txt file contains few lines of data, e.g.

```
2021 10 21 11 17 11 22 20842
2021 10 21 11 22 11 27 20842
2021 10 21 12 52 12 57 20843
2021 10 21 12 57 13 02 20843
```

(year month day hour minute orbit)

What I need is to check if the last columnt contains the same number, if yes, then I have to create new line from lines with same orbit number with earliest starttime in column 3-4 and latest endtime in column 5-6. So, the expected result is:

```
2021 10 21 11 17 11 27 20842
2021 10 21 12 52 13 02 20843
```

So, the question - is that possible and what modules should I use, can someone give a hint?

Comment: Your question doesnt seem very clear to me. Could you expand on what you are trying to do?

Comment: I have to combine lines with same orbit number. Each line contains year, month, day, starttime(hour,minute), endtime(hour,minute), orbit. If the orbit is same in different lines, I need to create new line, with same date, earliest starttime, latest endtime and orbit. E.g. if I have three lines with same date&orbit and different starttimes 11 16, 11 20 11 30, and endtimes 11:24 11: 28 and 11: 36, I want to combine this 3 lines into the one : { date} 11 16(earliest starttime among 3 lines with same orbit) 11 38(latest endtime among 3 lines) {orbit}